React Query useQuery can't trigger repeat call on click
I have a table of info where each row has a button to trigger a useQuery that will eventually open a new tab where more info about that row can be seen.
I can trigger the call to work as expected the first time clicking, however I can't get it to re-trigger and open another tab with that row's data.
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

const handleClick = async (product, label, id) => {
    await setSelectedId(Id);
    await refetch();
  };

  const {
    isFetched,
    isLoading,
    data,
    refetch,
  } = useQuery(
    [`some-{id}`],
    'some-url',
    {
      enabled: false, // set to false so can trigger with refetch()
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetched) {
      const link = getQueryParamsString(data)
      window.open(link);
    }
  }, [isLoading, isFetched, data]);

I added multiple useEffects to see if/when the useQuery bits triggered/retriggered...
first click
//// loading triggered
//// fetched triggered
//// data triggered

second click
nothing is output to the console log

Interestingly, if I click another row to open that info in a new tab I am given only
//// data triggered

Which makes sense as the data has changed from the call, but loading/fetched is not changed despite a different url constructed?

have you tried using forceRefetch: true inside useQuery?

disabling a query and calling refetch is fundamentally not how React Query works. This is an escape hatch to trigger imperative fetching, not the recommended approach.
Since you're storing things under the same QueryKey, multiple calls to refetch probably get deduplicated. To invoke a new fetch when the selected ids change, you'd want to add the selectedId to the QueryKey. That will store them separately and will trigger an automatic refetch:
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

const handleClick = (product, label, id) => {
  setSelectedId(Id);
};

  const {
    isFetched,
    isLoading,
    data,
    refetch,
  } = useQuery(
    [`some-{id}`, selectedId],
    'some-url',
    {
      enabled: !!selectedId
    },
  );

This is documented under the Lazy Query section in the docs:
https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/guides/disabling-queries#lazy-queries
